# Angular ui-select drop-down

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ui-select

The problem is when i place the ui-select inside an html element that have an overflow, the list of choices isn't comletely displayed.

Any help??

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bSzrgXFEPhwJBY66XT7P?p=preview).

```
 <ui-select ng-model="ctrl.person.selected" theme="select2" style="min-width: 150px;">
        <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="person in ctrl.people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">
          <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
          <small>
            email: {{person.email}}
            age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
          </small>
        </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```